# Show query result ONLY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, alias, output

How to execute a MySQL query and avoid having the query or an alias in the output ? I tried "" (empty string) as an alias but I didn't get the results expected as I ended up having a blank line.

**edit:** added some code

```
SELECT 
CONCAT("{\"counters\":{",
-- Total memory used calculation
    "\"mysql.total_memory\":",
    ((@@read_buffer_size + @@sort_buffer_size) * @@max_connections + @@key_buffer_size),",",
-- other monitored server status variables 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT("\"mysql.",LCASE(VARIABLE_NAME),"\":",VARIABLE_VALUE)
    )
,"}}")
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS
WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = "SLOW_QUERIES"
OR VARIABLE_NAME="Qcache_lowmem_prunes"
OR VARIABLE_NAME="SELECT_FULL_JOIN"
OR VARIABLE_NAME="SELECT_RANGE_CHECK"
OR VARIABLE_NAME="SELECT_SCAN"
OR VARIABLE_NAME="SELECT_RANGE";
```

I want to have a json format as output. I need this as an input for another software. This software doesn't accept a blank line among other things (compressed json format).

**edit2:** added output

```
CONCAT("{\"counters\":{",

    "\"mysql.total_memory\":",
    ((@@read_buffer_size + @@sort_buffer_size) * @@max_connections + @@key_buffer_size),",",

    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT("\"mysql.",LCASE(VARIABLE_NAME),"\":",VARIABLE_VALUE)
    )
,"}}")
{"counters":{"mysql.total_memory":39108608,"mysql.qcache_lowmem_prunes":0,"mysql.select_full_join":0,"mysql.select_range":0,"mysql.select_range_check":0,"mysql.select_scan":84,"mysql.slow_queries":0}}
```

I want to remove the "CONCAT(...)" part and only have the result as output.

Comment: Can you post the code of what you have tried already.

Comment: no idea what you're talking about. show some actual code.

Comment: I added the code, I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I know what you mean, you only want the outcome of the query printed without boxes and headers, therefore start your mysql client the following way: `mysql -uroot -p -s -r -N`.

This will supress output of the boxes arround the querys and also the column names. You can also use the -e Parameter to execute your query and then exit the mysql client after printing the results of your query to stdout, this is usefule when using it in scripts. Please see below (a simplified) example:

```
[root@db1 ~]# mysql -uroot -p******* -s -r -N -e "select 1+1"
2
[root@db1 ~]#
```

Comment: I know this answer is old AF, but it would be _very_ useful if you could explain what are all those extra CLI arguments :) Glad `mysql --help` is alpha-sorted, so...  `-N`: no column names; `-s`: silent; split results with tab; `-r`: won't convert fields(?); `-p` is to request the password and isn't really related.

Answer (score 0):

Every column in the resultset must be named.  But you can name with whatever explicit (non-empty) alias you wish. As documented under [`SELECT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html):

> A ***`select_expr`*** can be given an alias using **`AS alias_name`**.

Therefore, in your case:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
         '{"counters":{',
           -- Total memory used calculation
           '"mysql.total_memory":', (
                (@@read_buffer_size + @@sort_buffer_size) * @@max_connections
               + @@key_buffer_size
             ),',',

           -- other monitored server status variables 
           GROUP_CONCAT('"mysql.',LCASE(VARIABLE_NAME),'":',VARIABLE_VALUE),
         '}}'
       ) AS my_column   -- assign your chosen alias here <===================
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS
WHERE  VARIABLE_NAME IN (
         'SLOW_QUERIES',
         'Qcache_lowmem_prunes',
         'SELECT_FULL_JOIN',
         'SELECT_RANGE_CHECK',
         'SELECT_SCAN',
         'SELECT_RANGE'
       );
```

Comment: I tried "" (empty string) as an alias already. I don't want any alias ! just the result of the query.

Comment: @JohnTube: Why would you care?

Comment: I'm redirecting the output to another software as compressed json format so even a blank line is not accepted !

Comment: @JohnTube: Then your problem lies in whatever means you are using to "*redirect the output*", which should discard/omit the column headers (whatever their value).  Furthermore, one should really generate JSON from the MySQL resultset in that layer of your application, rather than in the RDBMS itself (which isn't really intended to produce serialised output).

Comment: I thought it was possible with MySQL. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JohnTube: Well, if using the MySQL command-line tool one can invoke with the [`--skip-column-names`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_skip-column-names) argument, but if this is how you are using MySQL then I fear you may be going about your application entirely the wrong way.